# Python Simple Loop Parallelization Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a simple python loop using Jupyter Notebook. I tried to use `Pool` but it just hangs forever and I have to kill the notebook to stop it.

```
def process_frame(f):
    new_dict = dict()
    pc_dict = calculate_area(fl)
    for key in pc_dict:
        if key not in new_dict:
            new_dict[key] = 0
        new_dict[key] = float(sum(pc_dict[key]))
    full_pc_dict[fl] = new_dict
```

`frames_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

I want to `process_frame` for each frame in the `frames_list`.

Note that the final outcome should be a dict with all the outputs from `process_frame`. I don't know if appending it at the end of the function may be a good idea.

Any suggestion on how to do this using Jupyter Notebook? Also, is it possible to have `tqdm` working with this parallel processing?

Kind regards

Comment: Yes, and append the `new_dict[key]` to a global dict at each step

Comment: `full_pc_dict`, I put in the end of `process_frame` in the post. Not sure if its the best place to do it, though

Comment: The idea is to run the for loop in parallel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[UPDATED]
If you want to use multiprocessing inside jupyter notebooks you want to use [multiprocess package](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/) instead of built-in `multiprocessing` (there's a known issue with main function of jupyter notebooks vs multiprocessing)

Create a separate `.py` file with your magic function. If you want to do it inside your notebook - use something like this in a separate code cell:

```py
%%writefile magic_functions.py

def magic_function(f):
    return f+10

def process_frame(f):
    # changed your logic here as I couldn't repro it
    return f, magic_function(f)
```

OUT: Writing magic_functions.py

And then run your code in parallel:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

from multiprocess import Pool
from magic_functions import process_frame

frames_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

max_pool = 5

with Pool(max_pool) as p:
    pool_outputs = list(
        tqdm(
            p.imap(process_frame,
                   frames_list),
            total=len(frames_list)
        )
    )    

print(pool_outputs)
new_dict = dict(pool_outputs)

print("dict:", new_dict)
```

OUT:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 37.63it/s]

[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14), (5, 15), (6, 16)]
dict: {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15, 6: 16}
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I need. However, when running this, I get `NameError: name 'calculate__area' is not defined`. I define that function early in the notebook. Is that a problem?

Comment: uhm… yes, that might be a problem. If I remember correctly you need to keep all the `functions` in a separate `.py` file (it will be read from multiple processes). And you need a proper import in place. I'll try to update my answer to reflect that

Comment: I tried it but I have no idea if it is working or not. When trying to interrupt the notebook to check some outputs, it hangs and I need to shutdown. Is there any way that I can have tqdm or some progress bar to check the multiprocessing?

Comment: I would advise to first run it on just a subset of your `frames_list`, e.g. first 10 elements or so. As for `tqdm` I will update my answer in a second to reflect that

Comment: @KarolŻak Is there a way to pass variables to `process_frame`? 
E.g. defining  `number=10` in the main and passing it to `process_frame` and `magic_function` to be able to return `f+number`

Comment: @shamalaia yeah sure. You can check out `partial` from `functools` package.
Then instead of passing function you pass in something along: ```partial(func_name, arg1, arg2, arg2, etc...)
docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial